# delete remote branch origin

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

I deleted a branch with :

```
git branch -d branch_name
```

And I pushed, but when I list the branches with :

```
git branch -avv
```

I see that the branch is always present with the name `remotes/origin/branch_name`.

How can I delete the branch from there?

Comment: You only deleted the branch locally, to delete it in the remote you have to do `git push origin -d branch_name` as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen But would that remove the local tracking branch as well?  At least, I might expect a `git fetch` would be necessary, but maybe not even that would be enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen when I use git push origin -d branch_name I get the following error : error: unable to delete 'branch_name' : remote ref does not exist

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When you delete a branch with `git branch -d branch_name` you just delete the local one. Push will not affect the status of the remote, so origin/branch_name will remain. If you want to delete it you should do `git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name>` as explained in the post suggested as duplicate.

When someone else delete a branch in the remote (origin) a ref to it will be present in your local repository, so after a pull or fetch you will still see `origin/branch_name`. To delete this ref you have to fetch with --prune.

```
git fetch --prune
```

If you want you can also combine it inside the pull command.

```
git pull --prune
```

Comment: when I use git push <remote_name> --delete <branch_name> I get the following error : error: unable to delete 'branch_name' : remote ref does not exist

Comment: @BrahimLAMJAGUAR the command is correct, for example I tested it with `git push origin --delete branchA`. Please check your command, or check if the branch really exist.
Also, please note that `push --delete` was not present in old git version, check your version with `git --version`. If it's an old one you can use `git push <remote_name> :<branch_name>`